# Swift Generics - Changing Values and Passing Between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'd like to use a variable of type `Any` in order to pass different classes to a child view controller. For example, I might have Table, Chair and Plate objects. In my child view controller, I'd like to change the value of one of their properties (e.g. Table.legs was 4, change that to 3), and for the parent view controller to be able to read that from the child VC. I'll use a Protocol to update the parent VC that can pop the child after reading the updated object.

In order to work out how the passing of generics might work, I wrote this code in a playground:

```
class Table {
    var legs: Int
    var material: String
    init(legs: Int, material: String) {
        self.legs = legs
        self.material = material
    }
}
var anObject: Any?

// set up the Table
let aTable = Table(legs: 4, material: "Oak")

// set anObject to be the Table
anObject = aTable

// get the object and change it
let bTable = anObject as! Table
bTable.legs = 3

// get the original object and cast it as a Table
let cTable = anObject as! Table

print(cTable.legs) // prints 3
```

I believe from this, I should be able to do what I describe above without any issues, because the original object reference (`anObject`) is updated whenever I update a variable referencing it.

My question is this - are there any pitfalls I should be aware of when adopting this approach? It appears that rather than creating a copy of an object, swift will always create a pointer to the original object; are there any situations when that does not hold true?

Appologies if this is seen as a fairly basic question, but this is all fairly new to me - many thanks in advance!

Comment: if you use `class`, then it will be you passing pointer, if you use `struct`, you will pass value, mean creating copy, thats all

Comment: In the Swift manual, read up on *value types* (which are copied on assignment) and *reference types* (where a reference is passed instead).

Comment: Classes are reference types, while structs are value types; try using `struct Table` instead of `class Table` and you will see a different result.  Using `Any` is probably not a good idea though; you would be better using a common superclass, such as `Furniture`.  By using `Any` you will have to keep downcasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class` are reference types as you noticed, if you assign an instance of the class to a variable, it keep the reference (the pointer in memory) to the instance and not the value copy.

`Struct` are value types, if you copy the instance of the structure to another variable, it's just copied to the variable.